# How to access into the description of a sub menu

Tags: menus, sub-menu, description

Well, I'm trying to get the description of a menu item and of a sub menu with the code attached below, but I'm not able to get it.

I'm trying to get the description of "About us" and the description of "Our board staff":

[image: About us and Our board and staff]

For the menu item (About us) is working good but for some reason the sub menu (Our board and staff) doesn't contain the information `description` and it just have `ID`, `URL` and `Title`, I already tried a `var_dump()` of the sub menu object (as you can see it in the code below) but it doesn't has it.

```
function get_menu_section_description($sectionUrl){     

    $menu = wp_get_menu_array("menu");

    $desc = "";

    foreach ($menu as $key => $item){
        $arr = $item['url'];
        // var_dump($item);
        if ($sectionUrl == $arr[0]) {
            $desc = $item['description'];
        }

        if(sizeof($item['children']) > 0){
            foreach ($item['children'] as $key => $children){
                // var_dump($children);
                $arr2 = $children['url'];
                if ($sectionUrl == $arr2) {
                    $desc = $children['description'];
                }
            }
        }   }   return $desc; }
```

Anyone know why doesn't have the description item, how to activate it or a possible solution for that?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution few days a go, so may it help someone, the problem I had was was the function to call the menu `wp_get_menu_array()`, there I had to add the description in the sub menu:

```
/**
 * Get a simple array of menu mapped, including the submenus
 *
 * @param array $current_menu Argument where you send the slug of the menu that you want to map.
 * @return array returns a simple array with the information.
 */
function wp_get_menu_array($current_menu) {

    $array_menu = wp_get_nav_menu_items($current_menu);
    $menu = array();
    foreach ($array_menu as $m) {

        if (empty($m->menu_item_parent)) {
            $menu[$m->ID] = array();
            $menu[$m->ID]['ID']      =   $m->ID;
            $menu[$m->ID]['title']       =   $m->title;
            $menu[$m->ID]['url']         =   $m->url;
            $menu[$m->ID]['classes']     =   $m->classes;
            $menu[$m->ID]['description']     =   $m->description;
            $menu[$m->ID]['children']    =   array();
        }
    }
    $submenu = array();
    foreach ($array_menu as $m) {
        if ($m->menu_item_parent) {
            $submenu[$m->ID] = array();
            $submenu[$m->ID]['ID']       =   $m->ID;
            $submenu[$m->ID]['title']    =   $m->title;
            $submenu[$m->ID]['url']  =   $m->url;
            $submenu[$m->ID]['description']  =   $m->description; //Line added;
            $menu[$m->menu_item_parent]['children'][$m->ID] = $submenu[$m->ID];
        }
    }
    return $menu;

}
```